# How can overload template's functions?

Tags: c++, class, templates

For example I have following class:

```
template<typename _Type>
class MyClass
{
   MyClass();
   const MyClass<_Type>& operator*(const MyClass<_Type> &inc);
}

template<typename _Type>
const MyClass<_Type>& MyClass::operator*(const MyClass<_Type> &inc) // very much errors
{
   //something
}
```

How I may do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: As any class/struct also template classes must have a terminatng `;` after the declaration:

```
  template<typename _Type>
  class MyClass
  {
     // ...
  };
// ^
```

Next error from your sample, you forgot to specify the template type:

```
template<typename _Type>
const MyClass<_Type>& MyClass<_Type>::operator*(const MyClass<_Type> &inc)
                          // ^^^^^^^
{
   //something
}
```

Also you might notice, that this is simply definition of the template class method not *overloadng*.

Comment: OP also forgot the semi-colon after the class declaration. `class MyClass{};` <-- there.